# Why is NSData(contentsOfURL: url) always nil?

Tags: swift, nsdata

I download a file from the DocumentPicker (iCloud, dropbox, etc.). This file can be .pages, .docx, .pdf,...

When I want to convert it to NSData for file upload, I always receive a nil value:

```
if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(urlToFile!.path!) {
  let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlToFile!) // initializer returns nil, although file and path exist
  println(data) // prints nil
}
else {
  println("Does not exist")
}
```

I cannot figure out why it is nil, the file exists at this path!
Where is my mistake?

**Some more information**

A screenshot, showing that it is not a scope problem, but the initializer (as stated in my question-title) already returns nil. In this example I use a suggestion from an answer below, utilizing `contentsOfFile`

[image]

**Utilizing an ErrorPointer**

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 257.)" UserInfo=0x7fac556cbf00 {NSFilePath=SUPERLONGPATH<NSUnderlyingError=0x7fac570beb20 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"})

**File's origin**

The file is downloaded via an DocumentPicker:

```
let docPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.content"], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
docPicker.delegate = self
docPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
self.presentViewController(docPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)




func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
    labelDatei.text = "Bereit"
    labelDateiChose.text = url.lastPathComponent
    urlToFile = url
  }
```

**Solution**

As it happens .pages and .numbers "files" are no files, but folders(containers). So they cannot be uploaded. Using a .pdf works now. Thanks to all for help

Comment: Show your real code, including context, if you want real help.

Comment: Try `var error : NSError? ; let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlToFile!, options: nil, error: &error)` and print the error in the case of failure.

Comment: I did. And updated my question

Comment: "Permission denied" - Perhaps a sandboxing problem?

Comment: I added new code to the question to clear up the file's origin. Why is access forbidden for a file, downloaded from iCloud?

Comment: "Permission denied" You've answered your own question.

Comment: It turns out, that .pages files are no files at all, but folders ... That's why I get a denial

Answer (score -1):

It looks  scope problem. You're defining your local variable `data` inside the braces and it won't exist after the braces.

Get rid of the word `let`.

That way  you will  be assigning to a variable data from the enclosing scope

Comment: Sorry. This is not the answer. Check my comment on the other answer

Comment: As Matt says your NSData Init might fail **also**, but you most  definitely have a scope problem.